# Get Smallest Value In Array Of JSON Objects

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a list that looks something like this,

```
[{'Device': 'A', 'CPU': 10.7, 'RAM': 32.5}, {'Device': 'B', 'CPU': 4.2, 'RAM': 32.4}, {'Device': 'C', 'CPU': 0.7, 'RAM': 32.5}, {'Device': 'D', 'CPU': 57.8, 'RAM': 38.5}]
```

Basically I need to get the smallest CPU value from the array and I do not know the best way to approach this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
>>> devices = [{'Device': 'A', 'CPU': 10.7, 'RAM': 32.5}, {'Device': 'B', 'CPU': 4.2, 'RAM': 32.4}, {'Device': 'C', 'CPU': 0.7, 'RAM': 32.5}, {'Device': 'D', 'CPU': 57.8, 'RAM': 38.5}]
>>> min(devices, key = lambda x: x['CPU'])
{'Device': 'C', 'CPU': 0.7, 'RAM': 32.5}
```